# Yii2: How do change Pagination-Per-Page into RESTful Web Service API?

Tags: rest, pagination, yii2

I am developing an application using AngularJS for the frontend and
Yii2 for the backend.

The frontend requires a comprehensive array of all users.

In the documentation of Yii2,
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html
I can read the result divided by X-Pagination-Per-Page: 20

How do I set
X-Pagination-Per-Page: ALL
??

Comment: This is an old question, but in my opinion, you should not have the Back end return all the users in one query which could become very big with time.
Instead, your Front end should iterate all pages (using the Link header) until it reaches the end an concatenate all results.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using `yii\rest\ActiveController` as parent from your controller, you need to override the action index in your controller.

This is my code

```
class StnkController extends ActiveController{
    public $modelClass = "common\models\Stnk";

    public function actions(){
        $actions = parent::actions();
        unset($actions['index']);
        return $actions;
    }

    public function actionIndex(){
        $activeData = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Stnk::find(),
            'pagination' => [
                'defaultPageSize' => 2,
            ],
        ]);
        return $activeData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

See [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html#collections) example from official documentation.

You can set any necessary number by changing `pageSize` parameter of `pagination`:

```
return new ActiveDataProvider([
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
]);
```

Or you can disable `pagination` completely and show all available data like this:

```
return new ActiveDataProvider([
    'pagination' => false,
]);
```

I don't think this is a right way to pass `ALL` because it's taken directly from `pageSize` (which is number).

In case of disabling this header will not be added.

Answer (score 9):

[Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html#$pageSize-detail) says that you can get all records if you set **pageSize** less than 1.

But the **pageSize** must be in range of **pageSizeLimit**. **pageSizeLimit** has a default value [1, 50] so it can't be less than 1 unless you override it.

```php
return new ActiveDataProvider([
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSizeLimit' => [0, 50],
    ],
]);
```

Now you can set **pageSize** value to **0** to get all records.

Example;

> http://localhost/users?per-page=0

Answer (score 0):

code for the data items on index page per page in yii2 framework

insert code into the models\ModelnameSearch.php File into the $query statement

```
public $pageSize=10;

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' =>  ['pageSize' => $pageSize,],       
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the answers suggest to customize the pagination by creating a new `ActiveDataProvider`. By doing so you lost lost the default behaviours of the `yii\rest\IndexAction`, such as sorting and filtering.

In fact, `yii\rest\IndexAction` is pretty flexible and allows overriding the minimal you need. To customize only the pagination, you can set [the pagination property of the `IndexAction`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-indexaction#$pagination-detail) without having to create your own `ActiveDataProvider`, e.g.:

```php
class CatController extends \yii\rest\ActiveController
{
    public static $modelClass = '\app\models\Cat';

    public function actions()
    {
        return array_merge_recursive(parent::actions(), [
            'index' => [
                'pagination' => [
                    'defaultPageSize' => 50,
                    'pageSizeLimit' => [1, 50],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

The trick above is the use of `array_merge_recursive()` such that the custom params are merged with the default ones, leaving the other default behaviours to work.

The entire list of pagination parameters can be found in the [API doc](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-pagination#$defaultPageSize-detail). It is up to you to decide the combination that fits the application most, e.g.:

- set a larger `defaultPageSize`
- set `pageSizeLimit` to allow `pageSize` of 0, i.e. all items
- disable pagination at all by setting it to `false`

Answer (score -1):

In yii/rest/IndexAction.php change

```
return new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $modelClass::find(),
    ]);
```

to

```
return new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $modelClass::find(),
        'pagination' => false,
    ]);
```

That's all.

Comment: You should definitely not change the `IndexAction.php` within the framework. Imagine you were to update your dependencies, you would have to redo the change. Either use on of the other answers to do so, or create your own action as subclass from the class above and do your changes there.